# Алгоритмы и структуры данных (задача на c++)

Tags: c++

Не знаю как решить задачу , условие такое:
Указатель на одномерный массив. Решить поставленную задачу с помощью указателя на массив. Все обращения к элементам массива осуществить не по индексу, а по указателю.
Дан массив из n целых чисел. Найти все максимальные элементы этого массива (напечатать их номера). Затем преобразовать исходный массив по правилу: первый максимальный элемент увеличить на 1, второй — на 2 и т.д.

Comment: Ну решите с индексами, а потом замените все `a[i]` на `*(a+i)`. А потом сообразите, как упростить...

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот Вам решение без указателей.... есть итераторы, но если сделать &(*(it)) то будет указатель, так и отмажтесь у препода)))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    const std::uint64_t size{ 10 };
    std::array<uint64_t, size> arr{ 1, 2, 6, 4, 2, 2, 3, 6, 6, 1 };

    std::copy(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), std::ostream_iterator<uint64_t>{std::cout, " "});
    std::cout << std::endl;

    auto max = *(std::max_element(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr)));
    int k{ 0 };
    std::transform(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), std::begin(arr), [&](uint64_t val) {if (val == max) {val += ++k ; } return val;});

    std::copy(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), std::ostream_iterator<uint64_t>{std::cout, " "});
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```